# Displaying Multiple GIF and/or WEBP at the same time using Fresco

Tags: android, fresco

I'm using Fresco to load and display GIF and WEBP for my app.

I have a `Gridlayout` where I display a list of GIF and WEBP. Images are animating as intented but one thing I notice is that they are not animated at the same time. Some images wait for the other to finish animating before it starts its own animation which is not the way I expect it to be.

Does anyone experienced this before? How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This should work out-of-the-box.
Take a look at the [animation sample app](https://github.com/facebook/fresco/tree/master/samples/animation), where we have 2 animations in parallel (and they animate at the same time).

Comment: I tried the sample app. And it's working fine smoothly for a while and then when I tried to modify it by making it a GridView of at least 6 GIF, it started to have a lagging effect (some GIF will suddenly stop, then continue playing again after a while).

Comment: I'm setting ```setAutoPlayAnimations``` btw. Is this what's causing it? But I want to play all gifs in the grid in parallel. What should I do?

Comment: how big are your GIFs? If you play >6 animations in parallel with a high resolution / file size / many frames, this will be quite memory heavy and Fresco can't cache everything. This will result in re-decoding of the frames, which can be too slow if it has to do this for all the views. Also, if this is a grid view that can scroll, are you sure that you don't also animate the GIFs that are not visible? You can try and limit the number of GIFs or use very short / small GIFs to see if it works.

Comment: hmm it might be the file size. there are a bunch of webp/gif assets that I managed to play smoothly though there are still instance where I'm using a dozen of 45kb webp and the problem still occurs. Might have to look at the view recycling parts.